# How to get moksha? And how does moksha work?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, krishna, moksha

Who gets moksha? Does someone get moksha after a certain age? Someone who is performing his duty gets moksha or does chanting the name of lord is enough? Duty or Devotion? What if somebody dies very young ? How will they get moksha?

Comment: Before asking, it is best to search first. There are many questions asked on this topic already.

Comment: Check this; https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moksha?tab=newest&page=1&pagesize=50

Comment: Everything depends on what you want to do AFTER moksha :-)